# How to render a HTML string in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a string like `< b >hi< /b >`. I have to render it as "**hi**". Can someone let me know an equivalent thing like `innerHTML` in Angular that I can use in React?

Comment: is `ReactDOM.Render()` not doing the job?

Comment: Not enough information

Answer (score 49, accepted):

you can try `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with the enclosing tag:

```html
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: yourhtml }} />
```

Comment: what's the safe way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

To avoid the potential security vulnerabilities (such as XSS attacks) that are present when using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you can do the following:

First use [DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) to clean the HTML.

`import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';`

`let clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirtyHtmlString, {USE_PROFILES: {html: true}});`

Then it can be rendered using [react-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-html) as Salman Lone said:

`import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';`

```
<div>
   {renderHTML(clean)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to official [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous. For example:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Comment: What extra information does this add, other than quoting the docs? The answer over an hour earlier points to the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I used following pacakge.

[react-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-html)

Answer (score 1):

According to the website "https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html" you should use dangerouslySetInnerHTML in order to avoid cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. However, if you are controlling the string that you want to render then that may not be necessary. If you wish to render HTML this way then as the above website explains, you may do so in this way:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

I personally do not like the dangerouslySetInnerHTML method (mostly because it has the word dangerous and that scares me). I cannot say if the next method is better, safer, faster etc but I like it much more. The second method that you can use is to render the HTML with useRef.

An example of this method is:

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function Example() {
    const aRef = useRef()
    const content = '<p style="color:red">hello</p><h1>world</h1>'

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(aRef==null)return
        aRef.current.innerHTML = content
    },[aRef, content])

    return <div ref={aRef}/>
}
```

I forgot to do testing for setting class, id, ref, values etc via string.
If someone wants to add to this answer, please add examples for every React operation like I have done with style.